# Display All Disabled ADUsers and their ADGroup Membership

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, import

I am trying to create a script that will do the above,

I did something like that:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled | Export-Csv -Path C:\csv\DisabledUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
$csv = Import-Csv -Path c:\csv\DisabledUsers.csv
foreach ($SamAccountName in $csv)
{
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | format table | Export-Csv -Path C:\csv\DisabledUsersGroupM.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

It is work fine until the `foreach` part. Seems like no values imported from the CSV.

I get this:

```
cmdlet Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership at command pipeline position
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Identity:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` without a required parameter (the identity of the object whose group membership you want to obtain).

Change

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

to

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $SamAccountName
```

Also, the `Export-Csv` inside the loop would overwrite the output file with every iteration, so you'd end up with just the groups of the last user. Add the parameter `-Append` to avoid this.

With that said, a much simpler approach would probably be a pipeline like this:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled |
    Select-Object SamAccountName, @{n='Groups';e={(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName | Select-Object -Expand Name) -join ';'}} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\csv\DisabledUsers.csv' -NoType
```